# Migrate users and permissions from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have migrated MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010. The problem i am facing is while loging into SharePoint sites.

The only user who can login is the site collection administrator.

Need help.

Note:

note that when i have migrated the stuff from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010. I observed that the users were displaying as: aspnetsqlmembershipprovider:username@domain.com

on the other hand, the users must be displayed as:

i : 0 # . f | aspnetsqlmembershipprovider | username@domain.com .

Answer (score 1):

Try using the MigrateUsers() Method of the SP WebApplication.

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication "http://yoursitecollection:port"
$w.MigrateUsers($True)
```

See the following:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhirajm/archive/2010/08/09/migrate-moss-2007-fba-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554321.aspx

Note that if you have Roles, those will need to be migrated separately. see :

http://codenice.com/migrate-users-permissions-from-sharepoint-2007-fba-site-to-sharepoint-2010-fba-site/